# Function used in query criteria - run-time error 2486

Tags: function, ms-access, vba

I'm quite new to Access and programming in general.

I have a database of users which have different statuses ie. Active, Inactive, VIP. I'm making a report that gets it's data from a query. One of the query's criteria should match the checkboxes.

[image: Checkboxes]

I created a function SeznamClanov() which returns a string that I use as Criteria in my Query.

```
Public Function SeznamClanov() As String

Dim Predhodnik As Boolean

DoCmd.OpenForm "IzpisClanovSubF"

Predhodnik = False

If Forms!IzpisClanovSubF!CheckAktivni.Value <> 0 Then
    SeznamClanov = "1"
    Predhodnik = True
End If

If Forms!IzpisClanovSubF!CheckNeaktivni.Value <> 0 Then
    If Predhodnik = True Then
    SeznamClanov = SeznamClanov & "& 2"
    Else
    SeznamClanov = SeznamClanov & "2"
    End If

    Predhodnik = True
End If

If Forms!IzpisClanovSubF!CheckIzpisani.Value <> 0 Then
    If Predhodnik = True Then
    SeznamClanov = SeznamClanov & " & 4"
    Else
    SeznamClanov = SeznamClanov & "4"
    End If

    Predhodnik = True
End If

If Forms!IzpisClanovSubF!CheckPokojni.Value <> 0 Then
    If Predhodnik = True Then
    SeznamClanov = SeznamClanov & " & 5"
    Else
    SeznamClanov = SeznamClanov & "5"
    End If

    Predhodnik = True
End If

If Forms!IzpisClanovSubF!CheckVIP.Value <> 0 Then
    If Predhodnik = True Then
    SeznamClanov = SeznamClanov & " & 6"
    Else
    SeznamClanov = SeznamClanov & "6"
    End If

End If

End Function
```

When I go through this function step by step, everything works fine. The problem is when I use this function in a Query - I get an error: Run-time error '2486': You can't carry out this action at present time.

When I run the debug tool it stops at the line

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "IzpisClanovSubF"
```

Why am I getting this error? Is there an easier way of approaching this problem?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Best regards!

Comment: I have serious problems reading what looks like obfuscated symbols. Or probably non-english naming conventions. Also, please do not include links to images (rather add them in markdown).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that - open the form for each and every record.

Remove this command from the function:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "IzpisClanovSubF"
```

and run it before you open the query.

Comment: I don't open the form for every record. There is a button on the form which should open a Report that lists users based on the choices made in the checkboxes. Every user has a status (ie.: 1=Active, 2= Inactive, 6 = VIP, etc.) If you click on a checkbox that says Active - I wan't the report display only a list of users with status Active. If you have checkboxes at Active and VIP - I want a list in the report with both those groups of users. I only call this function in the Query that is being used by this Report. SELECT [COLUMNS] WHERE ClanT.StatusClana=SeznamClanov()

Comment: You wrote: _The problem is when I use this function in a Query ..._  That's a no-no ... you don't open forms from running queries.

Comment: The Form is already open. When I press a button, this opens a Report. Report gets it's data from a query, which uses the function SeznamClanov() as Criteria (filter). The function gets it's data from the checkboxes on the Form and should return a string, whichs is used in the query.

Comment: If the form is open, there is no reason to try opening it again, so remove that line and you should be done.

Comment: If I comment out that line I get an error 2450 (Cannot find the refferenced Form). EDIT: I've found out that this does not happen if this form is opened directly, only when it is open as part of another form (as a subform). I have a navigation bar in a form that opens different subforms. This subform is in the navigation pane of two different forms. Is there a way to make a relative refference to a subform? I can't use Forms!NameOfParentForm!IzpisClanovSubF!CheckAktivni because there are different parent forms. Me.IzpisClanovSubF!CheckAktivni returns an error "Invalid use of Me keyword"

Comment: If you wish to refer to a specific subform not knowing the name of the parent form, you will have to loop through the subform controls (if any) of each form in the Forms collection (the forms currently open) and check the name of the form (sourceobject) that each subform control holds until a match.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I think I'm gonna ditch the submenu option and open it in the main form ...